# macOS Sierra slow to accept password at login

Tags: keyboard, password, login

In the last 2 days, I have found it difficult to login when I start up my mac pro retina. When I try to type in my password, I either have to retype the same letters multiple times or press the same letter key a few times before it is accepted.

I tried NVRAM reset, SMC reset - no different. I tried Apple support via chat and was instructed to set up a new test admin account - same problem remained. I rebooted in safe mode - the issue resolved. So I was told it was best to reinstall macOS Sierra in recovery mode, but the problem persisted after I reinstalled macOS Sierra.

It would probably be easiest to get a Genius Bar appointment and for an expert to look at my Mac, but I am going away for 6 weeks. Hopefully, I can get by until I return, but if anyone has any suggestions what could be the causes and what else I need to investigate to eliminate the problem, please let me know!

Comment: Do you only see this issue when you log in or do you notice a similar issue throughout typing on the Mac?

Comment: When you reinstall Sierra, was it Sierra only or did you restore all your "stuff" from a Time Machine backup?  If the latter, try again and don't migrate your data - leave it as a clean install.  There might be something that's conflicting.

Comment: I only see the issue at log-in but it types smoothly once I logged into my account. I re-installed Sierra only, not all my 'stuff' from Time Machine.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same issue since I installed the latest El Capitan Security update :/ VileVault is enabled, but I don't want to turn it off / reinstall my OS. Any ideas? Did you fix the problem?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what happened, but the issue suddenly disappeared after 6 weeks or so. I could not work out why, as I had not installed or deleted any new software or performed any software updates. So I did not have to contact Apple after all. Sorry not to be of any help!

Answer (score 1):

Today I've received my Macbook from warranty due to same problem and they have replaced I/O Board. Issue has been fixed.

Comment: Bad USB bus or bad device connected to the bus could mess up the key input buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Might the problem be with the FileVault on login ? Try turning it off in the settings and see if the login issue resolves. Then, maybe, try to fix permissions, on the main disk and reenable it ?

Comment: Actually, It resolved for me by removing the microsd card, which I use for storage. Need to investigate why is that now.

Comment: Thanks, but FileVault is off on my Mac. I think I will wait till I return from vacation and get an appointment with Apple to see if they can figure out what is the issue.