# macOS Startup Manager is very slow and laggy

Tags: macos, startup, dual-boot, bootable-disk

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) on the latest version of macOS Sierra (10.12.3 at the time of writing). Whenever I hold the Option key after turning on my Mac, it takes a long time (around 30 seconds) for Startup Manager to appear. When it does, it is extremely laggy. Cursor movements and arrow key presses take 10-15 seconds to register.

I have no external devices connected; I am using the trackpad and keyboard built into the laptop. I eventually plan to connect a USB drive to boot from, but I cannot get Startup Manager to work correctly even when only Macintosh HD is available.

I have already tried resetting the SMC and PRAM multiple times, which does not help. Also, I tried installing the rEFInd boot manager to see if it would work better. However, rEFInd is just as laggy as the default Startup Manager.

The only other person online to have the same problem posted this question:
[OSX Startup Manager (Boot drive selection screen) slow/un-responsive in Macbook Pro (early 2015)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245918/osx-startup-manager-boot-drive-selection-screen-slow-un-responsive-in-macbook)

Unlike that person, however, running `diskutil verifyvolume` on my `EFI` volume comes back with no errors. Likewise, `diskutil repairvolume` did not solve my problem. I have no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

I am suffering from same issue since December.

This is a hardware error, unfortunately it is hard to prove it to apple care. They will try os reload, factory reset ... before they realize it is hardware error.

Same issue here, noticed it in FileVault, but then realized it is there even on Boot selection section or even Diagnosis section. Disabling FileVault won't solve the issue, it will just cover it up.

I wasted a lot of time with software sides of things, reinstalling OS and all. they all didn't help. It is a Hardware issue.

I realized I have this issue once I started using SD Card reader for storing my files and extending my 128gb MBP. If SD Cards goes in, even for 1 second, and then take it out, boot is going to be slow until I do a NVRAM reset. Apple care didn't find any issue first time but second time they admit there is a hardware issue in my Macbook and they replaced it. I will report back issue returned.

You need to bring it to Apple care, and describe the issue in detail. I had to print a A4 paper with a detailed description (told them issue happen when put in a sd card and then take it out) and screenshot of diagnosis page showing SD Card error in diagnosis boot page (because for some reasons, it was randomly showing that error and apparently when I give my Macbook for first repair, it passed test 100% successfully) Reception who receive my Macbook, she didn't really reflect things I told to her to technician. She even typed issue of my macbook as "Booth up slow", you get the idea.

There are many users like us. I guess there are many other users who have this issue but are not aware of it. they just think it is normal to wait 30 to 60 seconds for boot and they never use filevault or boot option menu. I have found some here, this are all from SAME underlying issue:

- [macOS Sierra FileVault enabled freezing at login](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7691137?start=0&tstart=0)
- [macOS Sierra boot problem related to Apple SD Card reader driver](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261369/macos-sierra-boot-problem-related-to-apple-sd-card-reader-driver/273357#273357)
- [macOS Sierra slow to accept password at login](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258497/macos-sierra-slow-to-accept-password-at-login)
- [Whenever I enable FileVault, OSX is super slow to boot. I never had this problem before and don't know what changed.](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/46tlnt/whenever_i_enable_filevault_osx_is_super_slow_to/)
- [OSX Startup Manager (Boot drive selection screen) slow/un-responsive in Macbook Pro (early 2015)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245918/osx-startup-manager-boot-drive-selection-screen-slow-un-responsive-in-macbook)
- [OSX Boot drive selection screen is slow, un-responsive and takes forever to load in Macbook Pro (early 2015)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/265980/osx-boot-drive-selection-screen-is-slow-un-responsive-and-takes-forever-to-load/268902#268902)

Comment: Today I've received my Macbook Pro 13inch 2015 back from Warranty and they have replaced I/O Board. Issue has been fixed. I was experiencing exact same issue and now it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I am an expert in this particular problem. We spent many man-hours trying to solve and replicate this problem as we have over 60 laptops affected and increasing every week. Also spent enough time at the genius bar to know what are capable and what they can do for us.

I wont go in to details, we tried many many things. But what we have noticed is, it doesnt occur to laptops that are upgraded to sierra and didnt had the problem already. Upgrading to sierra after you have this problem, wont fix.  Other than that, we couldnt replicate it or fix it without part replacement.

We had all parts systematically replaced and replacing the IO board does the job.

UPDATE!! 10.12.4 firmware fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

@laapsaap is right. I had the very same problem, and Sierra 10.12.4 solves it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!.  Please refrain from adding comments in an Answer.  The preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to [your reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  Please see the [About] page and also [answer].

Comment: Well, that wasn't a thank you message. I wanted to confirm that that version of MacOS does solve the issue. I believe that reproducing something and communicate it is important for other people to judge whether something is true. A simple vote is not as informative, since it doesn't clarify the reason why it was given.